# How to solve $x$ in this equation?

Tags: trigonometry

In the process of solving a complicated problem, I finally got my last step as the following equation, and I am stuck with it. I simplified the equation a bit:

> $\sin (x) / \sin(110 - x) = C $ where $C$ is some constant.
>
> How can I solve $x$ in equation in such form?

Comment: You mean $$\frac{\sin x}{\sin(110°-x)}=C?$$

Comment: is this $$\sin(x)=C\sin(110^{\circ}-x)$$?

Comment: To both of you: Yes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can write $$\sin(x)=C(\cos(110^{\circ})\sin(x)-\sin(110^{\circ})\cos(x))$$
and after dividing by $$\sin(x)\ne 0$$
we get
$$1=C\left(\cos(110^{\circ})-\sin(110^{\circ})\cot(x)\right)$$

Comment: I think the sum of angle formula is wrong, but I guess it's a typo, and I have verified this method can yield the correct solution to my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For $(110°-x)\neq k\pi$

$$\frac{\sin x}{\sin(110 - x)} = C \iff \sin x= C\cdot\sin(110 - x)=C\cdot(\sin110°\cdot \cos x-\sin x\cdot \cos 110°)$$

$$\sin x (1+C\cdot \cos 110°)-C\cdot \sin110°\cdot \cos x=0$$
$$\cos x(\tan x (1+C\cdot \cos 110°)-C\cdot \sin110°)=0$$

that is

$$x=\frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi \quad \text{when} \quad C=\pm\frac{1}{\sin (20°}$$
$$\tan x=\frac{C\cdot \sin110°}{1+C\cdot \cos 110°} \quad \text{otherwise}$$

Comment: Take care : $\cos x=0$ has to be excluded. It is spurious case. If $x=90°+k180°$, unless we are with a very particular value of $C$, there is no solution.

Comment: Indeed we have to consider it if C has that particular value, otherwise I could not find the solution by $\tan x$. Am I wrong?

Comment: Let us take a moment. I think we are both right and wrong. Yes $\cos(x)$ has to be examined in this respect and for example $x=90°$ is a solution iff $C$ has the very particular value $C=\tfrac{1}{\sin 20°}$, but as it was presented $x=90° or 270°$ was unconditionally a solution...

Comment: @JeanMarie Yes I understand your observation. I try to better clarify and fix this point in my answer. Thanks.